# Is there a superposition principle of intensity of light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, superposition

If two sources, S1 and S2, of light are shining on a ball, and we are given the formula, L1(P) for the amount of light reflecting off the ball at point P caused by light source S1 and into a pixel, 'p', in the image plane of a camera.

Similarly L2(P) is the amount of light reflecting off the ball at point P caused by light source S2 and into the same pixel, 'p', on the same image plane of the same camera. Then can we say the total amount of reflected light at point 'P' on the ball's surface into pixel 'p' on the image plane is equal to L(P) = L1(P) + L2(P)?

In other words, is there a superposition principle for the intensity of light? It seems that when two lights shine on a surface, the resulting surface is always brighter.

Comment: No, in general you cannot say that the intensity of a superposition of two light sources will be the sum of their individual intensities. They could interfere and produce NO intensity at all at your camera pixel. 
Your claim becomes true when the two light sources are incoherent (which is basically the definition of incoherent light sources). Most light sources encountered in everyday life are in fact to a good approximation incoherent. I would expect that for something involving photography (which I guess is your application?) the assumption of incoherent light should be justified.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka why dont you make it an answer?